# Python and HTML: Not all arguments converted to a string

Tags: python, html

I writing HTML to a text file which is then read by the browser, but I get an error stating "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

But i can't see hwere im going wrong.

```
z.write('<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>'+k+'</td>' % k)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing parentheses:

```
z.write(('<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>'+k+'</td>') % k)
```

But it would be better not to mix concatenation and formatting.  So consider:

```
'<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%(k)s>%(k)s</td>' % {'k': k}
```

You might want to generate HTML using a dedicated tool.  Concatenating strings tends to lead to buggy and hard to parse HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You're using string concatenation in combination with substitution. Your substitution formatter `%s` is in the first string, but the `% k` applies to the last. You should do this:

```
'<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>%s</td>' % (k,k)
```

Or this:

```
('<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>'+k+'</td>') % k
```

Answer (score 0):

You get wrong and combining `+` and string formatting through `%`.  If `k` contains any %-sequence it would look like this:

```
'<td...species=%s>...%s...</td>' % k
```

You get two or more %-sequences and only one argument.  You probably want this instead:

```
'...species=%s>%s</td>' % (k, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

% k must be after string with %s

```
z.write('<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>' % k +k+'</td>')
```

or better

```
z.write('<td><a href=/Plone/query/species_strain?species=%s>%s</td>' % (k, k))
```